# Angularjs updating input from another input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I have following situation

I have following html Wh

```
 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" ng-model="c.num"  on-blur="test()" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="c.Id" ng-init="c.Id = pId" />
  </body>
```

On my controller I have

```
  $scope.test=function() { 
  $scope.pId = $scope.num+1;
  };
```

So that when 5 is entered in first box the second box should update 6. But it doesnt.
Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks 
Here is the plunker for it 
http://plnkr.co/edit/9QoMwsjUBl8CNAFgtYcj?p=preview

Comment: I think you forgot to paste the plunker link.

Comment: Yes I did, sorry about that. It is added on top. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! I just pasted my html over yours in the plunker and it seems to work as you desired. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3264/)**

- I removed the `ng-init`, no need for it.
- Referenced the right variable.
- Changed input type to number (then no need to parseInt). Else you would get 5+1 = 51.

  ```
  $scope.test=function() { 
    $scope.c.Id = $scope.c.num + 1;
  };
  ```

**Your [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cRw6cnOsgd2FSAinkSJ9?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

ng-blur is the way to go here:

markup:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter value" ng-model="num" ng-blur="test()" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="pId" />
</body>
```

controller

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.c = {};

  $scope.test = function() {
    $scope.pId = parseInt($scope.num) + 1;
  };
});
```

Comment: I updated the code to show some more info... use ng-blur to capture when focus is lost in the first input box to call `test` in your controller and use that method to set the value to pId

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the first ng-model is correct. I think you want this:

```
 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" ng-model="num"  on-blur="test()" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="c.Id" ng-init="c.Id = pId" />
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I am unsure what the object 'c' is or where it is instantiated. I also do not think you are using ng-init properly. In the documentation below, it suggests only using it in scopes that are otherwise unavailable in the angular context (e.g. ng-repeats).

What about changing your html to

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" ng-model="num"  ng-blur="test()" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="pId" />
</body>
```

and keeping your javascript the same.

Edit:
Angular documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit